# how to move file between buckets located in different projects using cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Just want to know is it possible to move file located in one project bucket to another project's bucket using cloud composer, it is working within same project and I am able to move file from one bucket to another, what if source and target buckets are in different bucket, how can I achieve this.

Comment: Buckets are just names in the global space. If your credentials can access the source and destination buckets, it does not matter which project owns the bucket.

Comment: how to do that, that's the question, where do I need to do the setting in IAM or airflow UI ? and how?

Comment: You would add the service account to IAM for each project that you want to access. Research Google Cloud IAM Service Accounts.,

Comment: this helped me, but I dont think its the safe solution https://gtseres.medium.com/using-service-accounts-across-projects-in-gcp-cf9473fef8f0

Comment: Your cloud composer is running under some service account. That service account should have relevant roles/permissions to work with GCP resources and services. Just make sure that the service account under discussion has an ability to work with the source and target GCS buckets in your context.  If you would like you might be able to provide those permissions at the same time as you deploy the cloud composer...